# jQuery's .isWindow method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to understand what I could from jQuery's animation functions, but ended up running into all sorts of internal functions I didn't understand, and ultimately landed on isWindow. The code for isWindow checks to see if an object has the property `setInterval`, and returns false otherwise.

Of course, any object could have the property `setInterval` without being the window, and although it would almost have to be a deliberate attempt to sabotage jQuery's functionality to have an object with that exact property name, I can imagine some reasonable cases where it could be unintentional.

Is there not a better way to check if an object is a window object? Couldn't they use something along the lines of

```
obj.setInterval && obj.setInterval.toString() == 'function setIternval(){ [native code] }
```

I know the return of `toString` of an internal function isn't going to be standard across all browsers, but the writers of jQuery seem to have a great understanding of these cross-browser differences. I'm also aware that this isn't a fool-proof method either, as someone could easily override the `toString` method to return that same string, but this would still prevent the problem of having an object mistaken for a window.

I wouldn't ask if I thought that `isWindow` was only used on internal objects by jQuery, but it was part of `isPlainObject`, which is used in `.extend`, which can be used on external objects.

Comment: "Of course, any object could have the property setInterval without being the window". How do you figure?

Comment: @j08691, How do you not figure how I figure?

Comment: I'm saying that since setInterval is a core JavaScript window function, how can any object have it? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @j08691, Because you could easily do `var a = {setInterval: function(){} }`. The functionality of setInterval can't be duplicated by an object, but the property name can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
function isWindow(obj) {
  var toString = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
  return toString == '[object global]' || toString == '[object Window]' || toString == '[object DOMWindow]';
}
```

Seems to work in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE and Safari (Newest versions)

Comment: +1 Because it's better than using toString on setInterval function, although still can be easily tricked by overriding `Object.prototype.toString` method.

Comment: More compact version :)
`function isWindow(obj) {
  return ['[object global]','[object Window]','[object DOMWindow]'].indexOf(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)) >= 0}`

Comment: Indeed more compact, if the Array#indexOf method is supported, which it isn't in IE8.