# $(window) not being recognised as a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I am trying to write a function that recognises if a javascript variable is the window. I have researched some ways to find out if a variable is the window but none seem to be working.

I have tried the following

```
  //define the variable as the window
  var myVariable  =$(window);


 //attempt 1 by comparing variable to window - showing not a window
 if(myVariable==window){
    console.log("window");
 }
 else{
    console.log("not a window"); 
 }

 //attempt 2 - showing not a window
 if(myVariable===window){
    console.log("window");
 }
 else{
    console.log("not a window"); 
 }

  //atttempt 3   - returns false - from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576283/jquerys-iswindow-method
  function isWindow(obj) {
        var toString = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
         return toString == '[object global]' || toString == '[object 
         Window]' || toString == '[object DOMWindow]';
  }

  ///attempt 4 - returns false
   function isWindowf(obj) { return ['[object global]','[object 
          Window]','[object DOMWindow]'].indexOf(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)) >= 0
 }
```

I am looking for a function that I can put a variable into and it will say whether the variable is the window e.g

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 //define the variable
 var myVariable=$(window);

 //put the variable into a function
 function checkIfMyVariableIsAWindow(myVariable  ){
     //if is a window then return true    
     if(/*code to run to see if is a window*/){ 
            console.log("is a window")
      }
      //if not a window then return false
      else{
           console.log("is not a window")
      }   
  }
  <script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: A jQuery object === window will never be true.  They are not the same type.

Comment: Ah that's why it's not working. Do you know a way to find out if a jquery object is a window?

Comment: `jqueryObject[0] === window`

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly

Comment: Why the markdown. I clearly stated the things I'd tried and showed what could be a common misunderstanding

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last statement.

Comment: Somebody downvoted my question and I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `myVariable[0]`, jQuery by default returns the array of DOM elements.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery by default returns the array of DOM elements, you have to use the first element of the array to access the DOM